# QtCreator and TBB under Windows

Tags: windows-7, qt-creator, tbb

I have compiled TBB from source using Mingw following the comment #5 in this post: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/291331. That went ok.

When I try to use the new TBB library in a QtCreator project, I end with this errors (ignore the warning messages): http://postimage.org/image/yrrecugix/

Here's the sample code I tried (I omit the non-tbb code):

```
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"

int main()
{
  tbb::task_scheduler_init init;
  /// more things.
}
```

And here's the *.pro* file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
#QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
INCLUDEPATH += "E:\TRABAJO\LIBRERIAS\tbb-4.1_src\include"
LIBS += -L"E:\TRABAJO\LIBRERIAS\tbb-4.1_src\build\windows_intel64_gcc_mingw4.5.4_debug\" \
        -ltbb_debug
```

Any idea?.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When built with MinGW on Windows, TBB binaries are `tbb.dll` and `tbb_debug.dll`. The option `-ltbb_debug` in your configuration files probably causes the linker to look for `libtbb_debug.<something>`. It can't find such a binary and reports about unresolved symbols.