# Building errors Qt creator with Tbb under Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, tbb

I compiled TBB library as shown [QtCreator and TBB under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606029/qtcreator-and-tbb-under-windows)
 set the necessary paths to the library (. Dll)

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Tbb\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\Tbb\build\windows_ia32_gcc_mingw_debug\" \
    -tbb_debug.dll"
```

as shown, but build the project I have the following error [image](http://i42.tinypic.com/qn1fh5.jpg), any ideas?

Comment: The error indicates, that you did not properly link against tbb library. I think, you need to use rather `tbb_debug.lib` than `tbb_debug.dll`.

Comment: In the folder that I build the library files with no extension .lib 
I downloaded sours codes website TBB and build them as shown above in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606029/qtcreator-and-tbb-under-windows)

Comment: You're not building in Release mode, right?

Comment: Yes,I build as show [QtCreator and TBB under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606029/qtcreator-and-tbb-under-windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use extensions for libraries to link (they are added automagically)
2. Understand command line switches :) `--library=namespec` has a shorthand version `-lnamespec`. Following that you defined command line switch `-t` with an argument `bb_debug.dll`, which is nonsense :)

You should use `-ltbb_debug`

Comment: I used `-ltbb_debug` But I have the Open unit performs the same mistakes, lest I wrong in Build

Comment: how I can solve the problem, please help me @friendzis

Comment: @m7boy sorry, could not understand your previous comment. You still get same errors? Make sure the directory you are providing to -L (`"C:\Tbb\build\windows_ia32_gcc_mingw_debug\"` in your example) contains `tbb_debug.lib`. If it is named `libtbb_debug.lib` then use `-llibtbb_debug` (as per your link).